# Integrating factor for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

okay so I think I did it correctly but the answer looks rather odd.

Question: Find the general solution of the DE

Reasoning:

$\frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4e^{-t^{2}}$

$\mu(t)=e^{t^{2}}$

$y(t)=\frac{4t+k}{e^{t^{2}}}$

Comment: @grahamkemp   helpplz!

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: If you ever have doubts about your solution being correct then you can differentiate it and plug it back into the ODE to see if it satisfies it.